# Error: object 'skim_without_charts' not found

Tags: r, data-cleaning, skim

I am new to R and trying my hands on cleaning data. I downloaded some packages then tried the `skim_without_charts()` function, but got this error:

```
Error: object 'skim_without_charts' not found.
```

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When I searched for that function (haven't heard of it before), it looks like it's in the `skimr` package. So you need to load that package first with `library(skimr)` - you'll need to do this one per R session, most people put all the `library()` calls they need at the top of their scripts. If that doesn't work, then you maybe don't have the `skimr` package installed on your computer, which you can do with `install.packages("skimr")`.

Comment: Hey Gregor, thanks for the tip. i think i was making a basic error, i went back and loaded the relevant packages and i was rid of the error. really appreciate your help. i had been stuck on that for like over a week now, im free to proceed now. Thanks again